# Confusion with independence relations in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, independence

What events would need to be independent for $P(A,B,C) = P(A)P(B|C)P(C)$ to be true?

What about $P(A,B,C) = P(A|B)P(B|C)P(C)$?

I know that we can use bayes rule to expand it, but with that I end up getting $P(A,B,C) = P(A,B,C)$

Comment: $A$ has to be independent of $B \cap C$.

Comment: how did u get that?

Comment: My comment was for the first question.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, as mentioned in the comments,

$$\begin{split}P(A\cap B\cap C)&=P(A)P(B|C)P(C)\\
&=P(A)P(B\cap C)\end{split}$$

Hence  $A$ and $B\cap C$ are independent (because $P(B\cap C|A)=P(B\cap C)$).

For the second one,

$$\begin{split}P(A\cap B\cap C)&=P(A|B)P(B|C)P(C)\end{split}$$

we clearly have

$$P(A|B)P(B|C)=P(A\cap B|C)$$

we know

$$P(A|B,C)P(B|C)=P(A\cap B|C)$$

therefore

$$P(A|B)=P(A|B,C)$$

so $A|B$ is independent of C.